# Python not replacing % symbol

Tags: python, replace, symbols

I have to replace the symbols in a string one of them is the % sign now I'm using this as an example

```
li = "this is () stuff %"
li.replace('()%', ' ')
```

but it doesnt replace anything at all if instead I do

```
li = "this is () stuff %"
li.replace('%', ' ')
```

then the % sign gets replaced no problem, if I take away the % and leave any other character in there, they also all get replaced, as soon as I put that % in there, the whole thing dont work.
The weird thing, is that I've tried on a different machine and it works no problem, it's just really weird

Am using python 2.5.2

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BTW, it's easy to solve your problem with `string.translate`

```
import string
table = string.maketrans('()%', '   ')
li = string.translate(li, table)
```

Answer (score 7):

`replace` matches and replaces the *entire* first argument with the second argument.

```
>>> 'abc'.replace('ab', '!')
'!c'
>>> 'abc'.replace('abd', '!')
'abc'
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `str.replace` replace only *complete* matches of its first argument. What you want can be done using regular expressions:

```
import re
li = "this is () stuff %"
li = re.sub('[()%]', ' ', li)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
li = "this is () stuff %"
li.replace('()%', ' ')
```

Why would you expect this to do anything? The string `"()%"` does not appear in your original string.

Also, you're throwing away the result of the replacement by not assigning it back to `li`.

Assuming you want to replace *each* of the characters with a space, then what you want is something like this:

```
for r in "()%":
   li = li.replace(r, " ")
```

You could also use the string's `translate` method.

```
from string import maketrans
li = li.translate(maketrans("()%", "   "))
```

Or you could also use a regular expression, though that requires that you learn about regular expressions, and as you're trying to learn about Python at the moment, that might be a bit much to tackle at the same time.